# How to stop abrupt end to game in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made a game in unity free. The game is functioning properly but if your computer receives any kind of notification, the game minimizes automatically and stops to work completely. Along with that, my computer freezes completely and I need to restart each time. Is there any solution to this problem in unity ?

Comment: This sounds a lot more like your computer is malfunctioning, especially if your machine crashes/freezes on other occasions too. Update drivers, make sure you aren't overclocking anything, uninstall all unnecessary software and run a virus scan. If that doesn't help check there isn't a hardware malfunction (try a clean install of OS).

Comment: Do you think so ? I suppose it is a possibility but  i don't think so. I opened the task manager when my computer froze and although it was not responding properly, my dis usage, cpu, and memory usage were all below 5%

Comment: If you get a full computer freeze at specific situations in an app this is a strong indicator for a general hardware/software problem. Especially if the CPU usage is low, so it's not just the app eating up all the CPU time. I would start with updating graphics and network (motherboard/system) drivers.

Comment: Nvm, i found another post on the problem on gamedev and it seems this is a known bug in unity.

Comment: can you post the link please?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/82260/why-do-i-seem-to-lose-control-of-my-computer-when-full-screen-unity-game-loses-f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the commenters below your questions, but to make sure your game runs regardless of window state, use this:

Application.runInBackground = true;

or this:

In the editor, go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Player. The inspector pane will now change to show the player settings. Look for the option that says "Run In Background" and check it.

This option will be held in both the editor preview and in built games.

Comment: Whoa thanks. Ill be sure to try this